# How to find the SUM (product_price) from the combination of two tables using JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, join, sum, right-join

I have two tables:

**table A**

invoicedate | client_id | shipment_id | weight | product_price

**table B**

invoicedate | client_id | shipment_id | weight

I am trying to create a new table C, which calculates a new column with the sum(product_price):
So I am expecting something like:
(Each client can have many shipments with the same shipment_id but the product_price changes
for each distinct shipment_id )
(In table B some weights are missing)

Example:
**Table A**

```
invoicedate | client_id | shipment_id | weight | product_price  
12/10/19         1111        888           48        36            
13/11/19         2222        111           30        45
12/10/19         1111        888           48        125         
12/10/19         1111        888           48        127.2
```

**Table B**

```
invoicedate | client_id | shipment_id | weight 
12/10/19         1111        888           48                    
13/11/19         2222        111           30       
12/10/19         1111        888           -                  
12/10/19         1111        888           48
```

**New Table C**

```
distinct(client_id)|invoicedate |  distinct(weight) | total_sum(product_price)

    1111           |   12/10/19 |       1111        |    (36+125+127.2)                   
    2222           |   13/11/19 |      2222         |        45
```

My code:

```
    create table C as 
    select A.invoicedate,A.shipment_id,A.weight,sum(A.product_price) as sum_product_price
    from A
    right join B on B.id=A.id
    group by  A.id, A.weight
```

The sum(product_price) is calculated wrong and I dont understand why..

Comment: Please explain `distinct(weight)`.  Also, tag with the data base you are using.

Comment: There is no column id in any table. Have you tried running your query without SUM to check the product price in the rows? Do you need to perform JOIN as you only SELECT columns from A table?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select A.client_id,A.invoicedate,A.weight,SUM(product_price)  from Table_A A
group by A.client_id,A.invoicedate ,A.weight
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a table from compiling two tables. So, this Reference will help you.

**CREATE TABLE Using Another Table**

A copy of an existing table can also be created using `CREATE TABLE`.

The following SQL creates a new table called "TestTables" (which is a copy of the "Customers" table):

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable AS
SELECT customername, contactname
FROM customers;
```

*So, after I tried this followed instructions, I tried by myself and that what I got*

*CREATE `'C'` TABLE:*

```
create table C AS
SELECT A.client_id as distinct(client_id), A.invoicedate, B.weight AS distinct(weight), SUM(product_price) AS total_sum(product_price)
FROM A, B
FULL OUTER JOIN A.client_id = B.client_id
group by A.client_id, B.invoicedate;
```

*SELECT STATEMENT:*

`SELECT * FROM C;`

**OUTPUT**

```
distinct(client_id)|invoicedate |  distinct(weight) | total_sum(product_price)

    1111           |   12/10/19 |       1111        |       133                
    2222           |   13/11/19 |       2222        |       133
```

***Reference:***
[SQL TABLE Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_table.asp)